# Handling exceptions when populating pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, exception, dataframe

I have set this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('artist', 'track', 'pos', 'neg', 'neu'))
```

and this code to populate it:

```
i = 0
for item in artist_track:
    artist = item[0]
    track = item[1]
    try:
        mood = track_mood(artist, track) # a function
        df.loc[i] = (artist, track, mood['pos'], mood['neg'], mood['neu'])
        i += 1
    except:
        print 'cant find {} lyrics'.format(track)
```

the code works when lyrics are found, but I'm losing `artist` and `track` entries for each exception raised.

how can I add `'artist'`and `'track'` to dataframe with `0.0` values for `'pos'`, `'neg'` and `'neu'` when exceptions are raised?

traceback:

```
   assert type(exception).__name__ == 'NameError'
AssertionError
```

Comment: What is the exception being raised?

Comment: `cant find Folsom Prison Blues - Live lyrics`, for instance. that is, when lyrics are not found by my function

Comment: What is the class of the exception? You should never use a bare except when catching exceptions.

Comment: don't know. exception prints only what was stated above

Comment: Edited my answer to include the check for the `AssertionError` that seems to be thrown.

Comment: I thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `try-except-finally` clause. Populate your values appropriately, and assign in `finally`.

```
try:
    mood = track_mood(artist, track) # a function
    pos, neg, neu = mood['pos'], mood['neg'], mood['neu']       
except AssertionError:
    pos = neg = neu = 0.0       
finally:
    df.loc[i] = (artist, track, pos, neg, neu)
    i += 1
```

In general, it is bad practice to use a bare `except` clause. Always catch only the error you are aware your code is going to throw, so you don't inadvertently swallow other unprecedented errors too.